# How do i create a namespace using kubernetes go-client from running container inside a cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I have a Kubernetes cluster and have a running container (X). From this container i want to create a new namespace, deploy a pod in this name space and spawn container(Y). I know kubernetes provides REST APIs. however, i am exploring goClient to do the same and not sure how to use namespace creation api.

Answer (score 10):

```
import (
    "github.com/golang/glog"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

clientConfig, err := config.createClientConfigFromFile()
if err != nil {
        glog.Fatalf("Failed to create a ClientConfig: %v. Exiting.", err)
}

clientset, err := clientset.NewForConfig(clientConfig)
if err != nil {
        glog.Fatalf("Failed to create a ClientSet: %v. Exiting.", err)
}

nsSpec := &v1.Namespace{ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{Name: ns}}

_, err := clientset.Core().Namespaces().Create(nsSpec)
}
```

Comment: createClientConfigFromFile() should find the service account token when run in a pod. If you have authorization turned on, you need to make sure the Pod's service account is authorized to create namespaces.

Comment: `Core` has been deprecated. Please update to use `CoreV1` in the answer.

Answer (score 9):

This one is works for me:

```
clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

nsName := &corev1.Namespace{
    ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
        Name: "my-new-namespace",
    },
}

clientset.CoreV1().Namespaces().Create(context.Background(), nsName, metav1.CreateOptions{})
```